# jquery trigger event on select box if selected value is clicked on

Tags: jquery, html, select

I am using this code for custom styled select menus:

```
 <div class="btn-wrap">
 <select id="myselect">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
 </select>
  <button type="button" class="btn">
  <span>Select option <span class="selection"></span></span><span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
 </div>
```

My jquery code:

```
$('.btn-wrap select').bind('change',function () {
  $(this).parents('.btn-wrap').find('.selection').text($(this).find('option:selected').text());
});
```

The problem is that if I don't want to have a selected value, so the select box assumes one as default value and if that option is clicked on, the 'change' even doesn't trigger.

I have tried using the following code but it's not working:

```
$("#myselect").attr("selectedIndex", -1);
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ArMq7/).

Any ideas?

edit: I have to state that the select box is absolutely positioned on top of my styled button with opacity:0 so using 'click' along with 'change' is a no go because it populates the list.

I have updated the fiddle so that the problem shows better (thanks for whoever created the original fiddle):

http://jsfiddle.net/ArMq7/6/

Try selecting the first option and see that the value isn't changed.

Comment: I've read your question three times and I still don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: Try, 
$("#myselect").on('change', function(){ --whatever you want to do--});

Comment: Why should change event be fired if there is no effective change??? Maybe you'd have better to explain what you are looking for instead. What about just setting a default value: http://jsfiddle.net/ArMq7/2/

Comment: If I understand correctly... Try binding change AND click although not sure of the validity of this and you'd need to stop propogation to stop multi firing

Comment: exactly, I am looking for an event other than change to trigger if the same option is clicked on. The above answer works when using the id but I have hundreds of select boxes so I'd rather I had it for a class.

Answer (score 3):

This could be what you are looking for, trigger manually onchange event:

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ArMq7/4/)

```
$('.btn-wrap select').bind('change',function () {
  $(this).parents('.btn-wrap').find('.selection').text($(this).find('option:selected').text());
}).change();
```

Comment: this autoselects all the default selected options; what I am looking for is have NO selected option at all when the page loads.

Comment: This was my intial thought, and this is what I used at first, however, on my style, the select is absolutely position on top of the button, so clicking there auto-populates the box. It's closer than other answer, but still no :/

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like.

```
<select id="myselect">
   <option value="0">Please Select</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

And change your jQuery code to

```
$('.btn-wrap select').bind('change',function () {
    if($(this).val() != '0'){
    $(this).parents('.btn-wrap').find('.selection').text($(this).find('option:selected').text());
    }
});
```

Comment: ..although this is what I am looking for as a result, I don't want an extra option to show. I know that using hidden disabled MIGHT do the trick, but on IE11 even hidden options are disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
<select id="myselect">
        <option value="0"></option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

You can also remove the first option after user selects a value - something like:

```
$("#myselect").change(function(){
    $("option[value='0']").remove();
});
```